# wsl: mount without sudo - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to mount a Windows partition inside wsl `ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`.  I added the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
\\192.168.2.42\c        /mnt/test                drvfs   noauto,defaults,user    0       0
```

It works if I run it with sudo like this:

```
sudo mount /mnt/test
```

Then I added a file to `/etc/sudoers.d/` with this context (also tried with my user and host name etc.):

```
ALL ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

I restartet wsl (also tried reboot):

```
net stop LxssManager
net start LxssManager
```

When I now run mount without sudo I still get:

```
mount /mnt/test

mount: only root can use "--options" option <3>init: (146) ERROR:
UtilCreateProcessAndWait:360: /bin/mount failed with status 0x100 No
error information
```

**Edit after feedback from @biswapriyo**

I was in the group sudo already (1st step).  The 2nd step mounts the drive when launching wsl.  `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
# Enable extra metadata options by default
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "defaults,user"
mountFsTab = true
```

It works because it is launched as root I suppose.  Nevertheless this is not what I need.  Background: I need to mount a remote VPN network drive by a shell script.  I don't always need it and it might not always be available.  So mounting on startup is not an option.

Comment: Try these two commands one or another or both with `root` user: 1. `usermod -aG sudo Heyman` or 2. add the `mountFsTab` flag in `/etc/wsl.conf` file as stated [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/).

Comment: work around might be using the wsl --mount command from powershell and make it run at startup of your machine. the when you access your ubuntu-wsl will be already there

Comment: @UncleSax this does not help since the VPN connection is not always available so I need this on demand not only on startup.